# Only allow 6 digit number or 8 digit number with 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angular-formly

I've created a validator that checks if digit is a number and makes sure there are 2 digits allowed after a decimal place. What this doesn't cover is a number that is either 6 digits with no decimal places (123456) or 8 digits with 2 decimal places (123456.78). This is what I came up with

```
function validateInt2Dec(value, min, max) {

    if (Math.sign(value) === -1) {
        var negativeValue = true;
        value = -value
    }

    if (!value) {
        return true;
    }
    var format = /^\d+\.?\d{0,2}$/.test(value);
    if (format) {
        if (value < min || value > max) {
            format = false;
        }
    }
    return format;
}
```

and its implementation in formly form

```
     vm.fields = [
             {
                className: 'row',
                fieldGroup: [
                    {
                        className: 'col-xs-6',
                        key: 'payment',
                        type: 'input',
                        templateOptions: {
                            label: 'Payment',
                            required: false,
                            maxlength: 8
                        },
                        validators: {
                            cost: function(viewValue, modelValue, scope) {
                                var value = modelValue || viewValue;
                                return validateInt2Dec(value);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ];
```

What do I have to add to cover above scenario?

Comment: Would it be wrong to add the missing ".00" (no decimal point), "00" (decimal point at the end) or "0" (decimal point has one following digit) before testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try regex below.

```js
var regex = /^\d{1,6}(\.\d{1,2})?$/;

console.log(regex.test("123456"));
console.log(regex.test("123456.78"));
console.log(regex.test("123456.00"));
console.log(regex.test("12345.00"));
console.log(regex.test("12345.0"));
console.log(regex.test("12345.6"));
console.log(regex.test("12.34"));
console.log(regex.test("123456.789"));
```

Comment: 123456.00 is a correct combination. It has 6 digits and 2 digits after decimal point. 1234567 would have been incorrect or 123456.123. I only allow 9 characters in that field so it's not going to allow user to enter 123456.123 anyway but 123456.00 should be accepted.

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk I saw your comment that "123456.00" looks incorrect. I've updated my regex - is it what you're looking for?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Tested and works as expected. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. If "123456." (dot as last character) is also correct you may want to change that regex to `/^\d{1,6}(\.\d{0,2})?$/`

Comment: No, no. It's absolutely fine. 123456. is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Trying this out on regex101 seems to fit you criteria.

Solution: `^(\d{6})?(\d{8}\.\d{2})?$`

- Group 1 `^(\d{6})?`- either 6 digits
- Group 2  `^(\d{6})?(\d{8}\.\d{2})?$` - or 8 digits with 2 decimal place

Comment: Doesn't allow any other numbers than 6 or 8 digits.

Comment: Here's the same regex without grouping `^(?:\d{6}|\d{8}\.\d{2})$`

Comment: does not match any number with two decimal places and < 8 digits on left side

Comment: @m8r1x accepts only 6 and 8 digits numbers. No shorter or longer. Also 123456.00 looks incorrect

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add additional regex complexity, what you can do is make an additional check of maxLength before finally giving it a pass

```
var str = value.toFixed(2);
var maxLength = (str.indexOf(".") > -1 ? 8 : 6);
if (str.length > maxLength) {
    return; //invalid input
}
```

Comment: This allows numbers such as 324.3454

Comment: Good catch! I fixed it by changing it to `value.toFixed(2).toString()` which takes care of additional decimal places.

Comment: I also noticed that `toFixed()` returns string itself, so the additional string conversion also isn't required.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toFixed' of undefined AND TypeError: value.toFixed is not a function

Comment: `Number.prototype.ToFixed` is [valid in ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed). As long as your `value` is a Number, it should be able to work. If you are passing an `undefined`, you should check that before passing it to this function.